# What is Abel's Formula for series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im studying Series.
Then I met the Theorem named Abel's Formula.

But I dont know why this Theorem is necessary.
I have no idea for what that Theorem means.

That is:

> For real sequences $\langle a_k:k\ge 1\rangle$ and $\langle b_k:k\ge 1\rangle$ and for each pair of integers $n\ge m\ge 1$ set $A_{m,n}:=\sum_{k=m}^na_k$. Then
>
> $$\sum_{k=m}^na_kb_k=A_{n,m}b_n-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_{k,m}(b_{k+1}-b_k)$$
>
> for all integers $n>m\ge 1$.

I understood the proof! I still dont know this Theorem.

Please help me to know this Theorem's MEAN.
And where can I use this Theorem efficiently. ༎ຶ‿༎ຶ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the discrete version of integration by parts (hence why it's often called summation by parts). As with integration by parts, it allows some sums to be solved such as in

$$\sum_{k=0}^nkr^k,~\sum_{k=0}^nk^2r^k,~\sum_{k=0}^nk^3\cos(2k)$$

and even when the sums cannot be directly evaluated, asymptotic behavior can be deduced, just like with integration by parts, such as with

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac k{\ln(k)}\sim\frac{n^2}{2\ln(n)}$$

especially when a part of the summand is alternating and behaves nicer when the averaged asymptotic behavior, where it can prove the convergence such as in

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)}k$$

which is Dirichlet's convergence test (but provides the asymptotic behavior).

Comment: Thank you for your interpretation. Then is this theorem used to prove some series' convergence?

Comment: Sure, such as in the provided example.

Comment: And I have a question in your interpretation, why sigma k/ln(k)(from k=2 to k=n) is similar to n^2/(2ln(n))?

Comment: Take $a_k=k$ and $b_k=1/\ln(k)$.

Comment: Wow now I understood what youre saying!!!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Umm, I have also question..  That is, if the right side of equation is infinite, then that series diverges?

Comment: Obviously yes?${}$

Comment: Thanks!!!! Now I knew it. :)